# How to keep track of the selected Fragment of a ViewPager when Activty is re-created (e.g. on rotation)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The MainActivity of my Android 4+ app uses a `ViewPager` to switch between 5 different Fragments. It is necessary, that both the Activity and the Fragments knows which Fragment is currently selected/displayed. The MainActivity keeps track of this information using the `ViewPagers` `OnPageChangeListener`. The MainActivity also keeps references to the Fragments created the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to be able to notify a Fragment when it is selected.

The problem is, that the MainActivty (of course) looses the references to the Fragments when it is re-created, e.g. when rotating the device. This would not be big problem, if the re-created MainActivity would re-get the information from the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, **but this is NOT the case.**

**It seems that the ViewPager automatically re-creates the Framgent(s) when `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`is called without asking the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.** This is a problem because this way the MainActivty does not get any information about the created Fragment and cannot save a reference to it.

How can this be solved?

```
// MainActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // When the activity is re-creates, e.g. on rotation, the viewPager
    // Fragments are created here without knowledge of the MainActivity. 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    currentPageIndex = -1;
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            updateCurrentPageIndex(position);
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onResume () {                
       super.onResume();
       updateCurrentPageIndex(currentPageIndex);
    }


    private void updateCurrentPageIndex(int index) {
        currentPageIndex = position;

        if (pageOneFragment != null && position == 0)
            pageOneFragment.onSelectedInViewPager();

        if (pageTwoFragment != null && position == 0)
            pageTwoFragment.onSelectedInViewPager();

        ...
    }


    Fragment pageOnFragment;
    Fragment pageTwoFragment;
    ...

    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        ...

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           Fragment fragment = null;

           if (position == 0) {
               pageOneFragment = PageOneFragmet.newInstance();
               fragment = pageOneFragment;
           }                          

           if (position == 1) {
               pageTwoFragment= PageTwoFragmet.newInstance();
               fragment = pageTwoFragment;
           } 

           ...

           return fragment;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers, but (I think) saving the instance state does not solve the problem. Of course I am aware of the possibility to save Date to the instance state. Thus getting back the information about the current index is not a big problem. The problem is, that the MainActivity cannot notify the selected Fragment because it has not reference to it. The Fragment is not created in the Adapter but automatically by the ViewPager. Thus the Activity does not get any information about the Fragment and has not possibility to notify it about being the active one...

Comment: i think this may help you [http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState).

Comment: I don't think that solves the actual problem. Please have a look at the edit I made to the question.

Comment: hmm can u try shared preferences , every change of index, save it to sharedpreferences , and when orientation change [handle runtime changes to get the index there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: As said in the linked documentation handling the configuration changes manually should only be considered as last resort because it makes it much harder work with alternative resources. The Activity uses different layouts for landscape and portrait mode. Handling these changes manually would very difficult. There has to be an easier way for the Activity to get to know the created fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface

```
public interface FragmentListener {
    void onFragmentActivated(Fragment f);
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity. Then in your fragment:

```
@Override 
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((FragmentListener)getActivity()).onFragmentActivated(this);
}
```

Now, when this callback is being called in your activity, you know which fragment is activated

Comment: Although this is a bit hacky (the Activity should know by itself when a "Sub Fragment" is created) this solution works quite well. There is not even a need to create an interface. The Activity can simply use `onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)`to get to know when an fragment is attached and check if the fragment is known or not...

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about onAttachFragment method

Answer (score 0):

In onSaveInstanceState() you should "put" anything that you want to keep track of.  In onCreate() you can "get" those items back out.

```
private static final String KEY_BUNDLE_CURRENT_PAGE_STATE = "current_page_state";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(KEY_BUNDLE_CURRENT_PAGE_STATE, currentPageIndex);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_CURRENT_PAGE_STATE) {
        currentPageIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_CURRENT_PAGE_STATE);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank, but this is not what I am looking for. Of course I am aware of the possibility to save Date to the instance state. Thus getting back the information about the current index is not a big problem. The problem is, that the MainActivity cannot notify the selected Fragment because it has not reference to it. The Fragment is not created in the Adapter but automatically by the ViewPager. Thus the Activity does not get any information about the Fragment and has not possibility to notify it about being the active one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private static final String INDEX = "f_index";
private int mCurrentIndex ; // the current index will be updated thru position
// orientation change occurs
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current index state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(INDEX, mCurrentIndex);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

...
// this is where we get the data back if we are recreated
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentIndex= savedInstanceState.getInt(INDEX);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

[image: A nice lifecycle here]
A nice diagram of lifecycle here.

**EDIT**

- If the above doesnt work for you I suggest trying this instead.

  1. try using shared preferences
  2. every change of index, save it to sharedpreferences
  3. when orientation change [handle runtime changes to get the index
     there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that solves the actual problem. Please have a look at the edit I made to the question.